# Why does the Mathematica give different numerical results?

Tags: numerics, arithmetic

Why do the two inputs give different values?

```
in:=(-y)^a /. a -> 2.99 /. y -> -2
out:=7.94474
```

and

```
in:=(-1)^a (y)^a /. a -> 2.99 /. y -> -2
out:=7.92906 - 0.498854 I
```

Answer (score 9):

They are supposed to be different.

```
(-y)^a /. a -> 2.99 /. y -> -2
(*7.94474*)
```

is equivalent to

```
2^2.99
```

or

```
Exp[2.99 Log[2]]
```

all giving the same answer whereas

```
(-1)^a (y)^a /. a -> 2.99 /. y -> -2
(*7.92906 -0.498854 I*)
```

is

```
(-1)^2.99
(*-0.999507 + 0.0314108 I*)
```

and

```
(-2)^2.99
(*-7.94082+0.24955 I*)

%%*%
(*7.92906 -0.498854 I*)
```

or another way

```
Exp[2.99 Log[-2]] Exp[2.99 Log[-1]]
(*7.92906 -0.498854 I*)
```

Powers and roots of complex numbers really do matter how and in what order they are calculated.

Answer (score 6):

Complex power is really a multivalued function. Consider this function, that returns all possible values of a complex number $x^y$:

```
complexPowers[x_, y_?NumericQ] := With[{r = Rationalize[y]},
  SortBy[ResourceFunction["ComplexRoots"][x, Denominator[r]]^Numerator[r], Arg]]
```

Also an auxiliary function to multiply them in all possible ways:

```
multiplyPowers[xs_ /; VectorQ[xs, NumericQ], ys_ /; VectorQ[ys, NumericQ]] := 
 SortBy[DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Outer[Times, xs, ys], Arg]
```

Then your example reduces to comparing all values of `complexPowers[-y, a]` and `multiplyPowers[complexPowers[-1, a], complexPowers[y, a]]`

```
complexPowers[-y, a] == multiplyPowers[complexPowers[-1, a], complexPowers[y, a]] /. {y -> -2, a -> 2.99}
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to write things in terms of symbols *without* minus signs flying around, you can use `PowerExpand`. If used naively, it treats all symbols as **positive real numbers** which is not always the case, and certainly is incorrect in OP's situation.

The trick is to *set all assumptions to true*, hence disabling all simplifications that are correct only for positive real numbers. Indeed, we have

```
PowerExpand[(-y)^a]
```

> $$(-1)^a y^a$$

whereas

```
PowerExpand[(-y)^a, Assumptions -> True]
```

> $$y^a e^{2 i \pi  a \left\lfloor -\frac{\arg (y)}{2 \pi }\right\rfloor +i \pi  a}$$

If you now set $\{a,y\}$ to any particular numbers you like, you get the correct result:

```
N[(E^(I a π+2 I a π Floor[-(Arg[y]/(2 π))]) y^a)/.y->-2/.a->299/100]
```

> 7.94474 +0. I

Similar to all numeric computations, one needs to be careful with potential finite precision errors. Indeed, we see that

```
(E^(I a π + 2 I a π Floor[-(Arg[y]/(2 π))]) y^a) /. y -> -2 /. a -> 2.99
```

> 7.94474 - 2.77556*10^-17 I

which can be avoided as we did in the first case (using 299/100 instead of 2.99 and hitting with `N` at the end) or we can try increased precision:

```
(E^(I a π + 2 I a π Floor[-(Arg[y]/(2 π))]) y^a) /.  y -> -2 /. a -> 2.99`10
```

> 7.94473996 + 0.*10^-8 I